# $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] guidance

Tags: php, uri

I had a strange coding situation where I needed to have the URI become the title of the page being viewed. I couldn't think of another way to do it but now I need to format that URI and can't figure out how to accomplish it. It is a WordPress site so the URI is pretty clean. What I want to do is capitalize the letter of the first word and then a space, dash or pipe delimiter to separate out the title.

So this obviously gives me the URI:

```
<title><?php echo ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ?></title>
```

which gives me something like /test-catalog/diagnosis/flu. What I want to display is Test Catalog - Diagnosis - Flu

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as a résumé of the previous answers:

```
echo ucwords(str_replace(array("-","/"),array(" "," - "),substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1)));
```

Answer (score 2):

I would imagine this would work:

```
echo ucwords(str_replace(Array("-","/"),Array(" "," - "),$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Answer (score 1):

By using str_replace and ucwords

### Example

`echo ucwords(str_replace('/', ' - ', str_replace('-', ' ', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])));`

Answer (score 1):

several things to do:

```
$url = str_replace("-"," ",$url);  // convert the - to spaces (do this first)
$url = str_replace("/"," - ",$url);  // convert the / to hyphens with spaces either side

$title = ucfirst($url);            // capitalize the first letter
```

if you want to capitalize each letter, then do this:

```
$title = ucwords($url);            // capitalize first letter of each word
```

you might have some whitepsace begining and end, so do this:

```
$title= trim($title)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// remove the first slash '/'
$uri = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1);
// ucwords to uppercase any word
// str_replace to replace "-" with " " and "/" with " - "
echo ucwords(str_replace(array("-","/"),array(" "," - "),$uri));
```

[codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/EAo7GP)